# Change the Design Pattern of an Unmanaged Package

Tags: apex, appexchange, package, unmanaged-package

One of our client is using Appexchange  app  and would like to change the Design Pattern of the app which is unmanaged Package.Do we have an option to change the Design ,Functionalty etc.Any Suggestion Plz.

Actually client is using "Store Builder" app from app exchange.

1)In this app he has added some android apps images and would like to reorder those once it is linked with the SDk devices.Do we use any SDK's in Salesforce.

2)The Design pattern should be customized as per requirement.

3)This app should get integrated with third party app which is a ecommerce app.

4)The Same app should be used in Mobile application.

Comment: @Mohith Shrivastava,@sfdc_ninja :Thanks for your reply.When stuided in the doc ,it states that Unmanaged packages should not be used to migrate components from a sandbox to production organization. Instead, use Change Sets. when  we use Developer edition .

Comment: That is correct.  How does that relate to the question?  Are you trying to use a an unmanaged package to migrate components between a sandbox and production?

Comment: @sfdc_ninja:I have updated my question.I have installed the app in Developer Edition.i tried adding the images but it didnt get added.I dont know which edition is the client using as of now.

Comment: I don't understand at all.  If this is an unmanaged package, you can change anything in it that you want.  Are you asking how to do all the things you just added to your question?  Thats a whole different question and you would have to tell us what you have attempted and where you are stuck.  As far as the original question, can I make changes to the unmanaged package....yes, you can.

Comment: @sfdc_ninja:Correct me if im wrong .My concern is in developer edition we dont have an option of change sets as well as migration.So if i want to migrate the unmanaged package how can i do that without change sets.Do we have any option.

Comment: You are not migrating from a sandbox instance of an org, to the production instance of an org.  That is when you would want to use change sets.  In your case, you want to package up some code and configuration from your dev org in order to put them in another org.  This is the perfect scenario for an unmanaged package.

Answer (score 1):

An unmanaged package is really just a one time 'drop' of a package of code and configuration into your org.  The creator of the package has no control over the installed components.  You can make any changes you want to the installed components, including the Apex code.  This package is really now your components that you control any changes over.

A managed package protects the Intellectual Property of the Apex Classes, so therefore you cannot see or edit the Apex code.

Think of an unmanaged package as a someone giving you a set of components that you now own and maintain moving forward.  The contents within a managed package is really owned and maintained by the creator.

You can find some more on this [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sharing_apps.htm&language=en_US).

Answer (score 0):

If its unmanaged app,you can change code and config .

Managed app restricts you from doing this but unmanaged app allows you to change code and config